# Manager offering annual leave I don’t think I’m due

Tags: united-kingdom, holidays

So our manager has only been in the job since Nov and he approached me today to tell me I have another week and a half to take off, which I was completely unaware of. I work part-time which does make my hours confusing, but my understanding was that I would get 4 weeks off plus public holidays (of which there are around 6 I think). I’ve been taking my 4 weeks off for years.

My concern is that the manager is mistaken. Should I take the time off since that was the direction? Or should I be covering my back? I don’t want pay docked or annual leave for 2019-2020 taken from me.

I’m in the UK if it matters.

Comment: Did you approach him/her about this?

Comment: I immediately told him the amount of hours I take each year and that I had concerns he was mistaken. He told me he was definitely right!

Comment: Does you pay stub or some other system/website track your days off?

Comment: There’s a board with all of the departments annual leave marked on, which can only be written on by the manager and I keep documentation of my own annual leave. So really only he tracks it, it’s not computerized.

Answer (score 2):

I think the key thing here is going to be *communication.*  Your manager is new on the job; it stands to reason that there be some things that they are not aware of.  Also, without talking with them, you cannot know *why* they gave you that direction: did he misunderstand the amount of vacation you usually get?  Was there a change in company policy you were unaware of?

Also, who gave you the contract to work?  Was it the previous manager, or was it a higher up?  If it was a higher up in the corporation, it would be wise to drop a line to that higher up confirming the general terms of the contract, after which you can work out details with the manager.  If it was the previous manager who gave you the contract, it would probably be a good idea to work out details with the new manager... and personally, I would try to *get it in writing,* for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Email HR and ask them to confirm the amount of remaining vacation days. Whatever their response, you now have a paper trail and should be able to act accordingly without adverse repercussions.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO,

Ask for one on one with manager, prepare your entitlement and usage details for 2018.

As another option you can send him that information, asking for confirmation that you are entitled for more than you already used.

Also you can mention that you would not want your 2019 time off to be affected by miscommunication

Getting the written answer for this email will cover you in case of manager`s misunderstanding